# Problem With Publishing a Self Contained EXE (Issue With Nuget)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-7, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I have created an application in c# using visual studio 2019. When I released it, everything worked fine but the exe came out with 2 other files in the folder. I want to have just one exe that can run by itself, without any extra files in its location, so I tried the "self contained" option in the publish settings. It didn't work though. I only get an "error has occured" popup window that says this:

```
Publish has encountered an error.
Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. 

A diagnostic log has been written to the following location:
"C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4E17.tmp"
```

And in the output box below I get this:

```
1>Determining projects to restore...
1>Unable to load the service index for source 
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
1>  An error occurred while sending the request.
1>  The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure 
channel.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped 
==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Now, I've seen some similar issues that people posted about this and some possible fixes, but nothing has worked for me. I have updated TLS 1.3->Client->DisabledByDefault value to 1 in regedit and it still didn't fix the problem.

I'm using system **windows 7 (32-bit)**. I'm looking forward to any possible fixes, thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please share the nuget name you used with us?

Answer (score 1):

**First**, please check if the problem is related to network or VS IDE.

Please enter the link `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` on the website and if you cannot open the website, I think the issue is related to your Internet and you should check your Internet and make sure that there is nothing else breaking it.

If not, I think the issue is related to VS IDE. You should try the following steps:

**1)** disable any third party vs installed extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions** to check if there is an extension cause that.

**2)** [clean all nuget caches first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or just delete all cache files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages`

**3)** enable only nuget.org nuget package source and disable the others.

Enter **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Sources**

[image]

Uncheck the other package sources and only remain `nuget.org`.

**Besides**, you can also change `nuget.org` package source as `http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/` or `https://nuget.org/api/v2/` to test whether it can resore nuget packages.

**4)** close VS, delete the global `nuget.config` file under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`. Then, restart your VS to regenerate the file, test again.

**5)** run these under CMD( run as **Administrator**)

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SystemDefaultTlsVersions /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:64
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SystemDefaultTlsVersions /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:32
```

**6)** [repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update it to the latest version

Comment: I have same issue as OP. Nuget restore works good on daily basis. Issue is visible only during **publishing** with option **self-contained** as deployment mode. Runtime .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue - Visual Studio 2019 but Windows 7 64 bit. I can't publish using a self-contained deployment mode under Visual Studio. I didn't found solution, but workaround is available.

**Workaround**

Publish from command line works. During first run nuget will be downloaded to local cache, so after this publish under Visual Studio will work too. Example:

```
dotnet publish ProjectName.csproj /p:PublishProfile=YourPublishProfileName
```

**Other possible workaround**

Use Windows 10. I moved project to PC with same Visual Studio, but with Windows 10. Publish from Visual Studio works without issues.